# Recursively adding subtrees to boost property tree

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I want to write a parameter server in C++ where I can recursively dump a tree of parameters into a property tree and then write it to a JSON file.
The dump function looks like this:

```cpp
void Params::dump(string filename) {
    // Create a root
    pt::ptree root;
 
    // Fill the root with parameters
    mapToPt(curParams, root);
 
   // Write to count
   pt::write_json(cout, root);
}
```

mapToPt is supposed to recursively go through the hierarchy of my parameter server and fill the property tree while doing so:

```cpp
void Params::mapToPt(boost::shared_ptr<Params> curParams, pt::ptree &root) {
    // Fill current root with parameters from curParams ParameterMap
    map<string, boost::shared_ptr<Param>>::iterator it;
    for (it = curParams->getParamMap().begin(); it != curParams-getParamMap().end(); it++) {
        root.put(it->first, it->second->getValue());
        cout << "Add Parameter: \n";
        cout << "Parameter name: " << it->first << "\n";
        cout << "Parameter value: " << it->second->getValue() << "\n";
    }
 
    // Recursively go through all children to do the same to them
    if(curParams->hasChildren()) { //ERROR LINE
        map<string, boost::shared_ptr<Params> >::iterator it;
        for(it = curParams->getChildren().begin(); it != curParams-getChildren().end(); it++) {
            pt::ptree new_tree;
            root.add_child(it->second->getName(), new_tree);
            cout << "Add Child: \n";
            cout << "Child name: " << it->second->getName() << "\n";
            mapToPt(it->second, new_tree);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that as soon as I go into recursion, errors occur at random lines that can not be the cause of the error. "basic_string::_M_construct null not valid" is the error message. I believe that I might access deleted content and that it might be due to the way I iterate through the property tree children.
Is my way of doing that wrong or is there another way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: If `hasChildren()` is the error  line, how is that implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is `mapToPt` a member when it also expects a pointer to a `Params` instance?

Anyhoops, there's quite a bit of confusion.

At a design level, your `Params` type looks like it cannot decide whether it's a leaf node or not. Moreover, it suffers from "Quasi Classes" design, where getters essentially guarantee that there is no class invariant possible. In such cases, prefer to just have a struct with member fields.

> Note, if you fail to return *by reference* from `getParamMap()` and `getChildren()` then you already have [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in both loops, because the iterators then point into non-existent copies of containers.
>
> You should check this. Also, see my working demo below

At the implementation level, this is causing you problems:

```
pt::ptree new_tree;
root.add_child(it->second->getName(), new_tree);
```

`add_child` inserts a copy of `new_tree`. Any future modification to `new_tree` has no effect. Instead, write:

```
pt::ptree& new_tree = root.add_child(it->second->getName(), {});
```

Here, `new_tree` becomes a *reference* to the actually added tree.

### Attempted Fix

The style is still below my expectations. Personally, I'd closely review the use of `shared_ptr` at all in this piece of code.

But this will probably help you along:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9e7310935115f44)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

struct Param {
    std::string getValue() const { return "42"; }
};

struct Params {
    using ParamMap = std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Param> >;
    using Children = std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Params> >;

    Params(std::string name = "") : _name(name) {}

    std::string getName() const         { return _name; }

    ParamMap& getParamMap()             { return _map; } 
    ParamMap const& getParamMap() const { return _map; } 

    bool hasChildren() const            { return !_children.empty(); }
    Children& getChildren()             { return _children; } 
    Children const& getChildren() const { return _children; } 

    static void mapToPt(boost::shared_ptr<Params> curParams, pt::ptree &root);

  private:
    std::string _name;
    ParamMap _map;
    Children _children;
};

void Params::mapToPt(boost::shared_ptr<Params> curParams, pt::ptree &root) {
    // Fill current root with parameters from curParams ParameterMap
    std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Param> >::iterator it;
    for (it = curParams->getParamMap().begin(); it != curParams->getParamMap().end(); it++) {
        root.put(it->first, it->second->getValue());
        //std::cout << "Add Parameter: \n";
        //std::cout << "Parameter name: " << it->first << "\n";
        //std::cout << "Parameter value: " << it->second->getValue() << "\n";
    }

    // Recursively go through all children to do the same to them
    if (curParams->hasChildren()) {
        for (auto it = curParams->getChildren().begin(); it != curParams->getChildren().end(); it++) {
            pt::ptree& new_tree = root.add_child(it->second->getName(), {});
            //std::cout << "Add Child: \n";
            //std::cout << "Child name: " << it->second->getName() << "\n";
            mapToPt(it->second, new_tree);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    auto a = boost::make_shared<Params>("rootparams");

    a->getParamMap().emplace("one", boost::make_shared<Param>());
    a->getParamMap().emplace("two", boost::make_shared<Param>());
    a->getParamMap().emplace("three", boost::make_shared<Param>());

    a->getChildren().emplace("child1", boost::make_shared<Params>("child1-name"))
        .first->second->getParamMap().emplace("four", boost::make_shared<Param>());

    a->getChildren().emplace("child2", boost::make_shared<Params>("child2-name"))
        .first->second->getParamMap().emplace("five", boost::make_shared<Param>());

    pt::ptree root;
    a->mapToPt(a, root);

    write_json(std::cout, root);
}
```

Prints

```
{
    "one": "42",
    "three": "42",
    "two": "42",
    "child1-name": {
        "four": "42"
    },
    "child2-name": {
        "five": "42"
    }
}
```